# Using Gitlab pipeline, how to pass commit-id (SHA) to my program running in Docker

Tags: dockerfile, gitlab-ci, argparse

I'm developing a Python service that runs in Docker. I'm using Gitlab pipeline for CD. How do I pass the Git commit-sha to my Python program?

Answer (score 0):

I did find the documentation on this unclear and it took me a bit of testing to get this working, so here are some code snippets in case others could benefit from it.

You can of course add build timestamp, git tags, etc, to this.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
build_image:
  script:
    - docker build -t my_image_name
        --build-arg COMMIT_SHA=$CI_COMMIT_SHA
        .
    - docker rm -f my_image_name || true
    - docker run -d --name my_container_name my_image_name:latest
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

# do some more installing and preparing

ARG COMMIT_SHA

LABEL COMMIT_SHA=$COMMIT_SHA

ENV ENV_COMMIT_SHA=$COMMIT_SHA

ENTRYPOINT python my_program.py --build_id=$ENV_COMMIT_SHA
```

my_program.py

```
import argparse

def main()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--build_id', dest='BUILD_ID', default='N/A')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args.BUILD_ID)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```